# Execute Ajax call once in a time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to trigger an Ajax call only once per period using JS. I'm dragging the thead of a table, so the event is triggered a lot.
So, if the user drags one thead it should reset the event time and invoke the Ajax call only when the user does not drag the thead again during this period.

I don't want to make an ajax request in short periods, because I know the user can move the thead to more than one position.

I couldn't find an option like that which would trigger the action once the user drop the thead.

I'm using datatables and the extension colReorder, btw. I tried checking some of the event keys and none of them seems to give the information that the thead was dropped.

The event is:

```
.on( 'column-reorder.dt', function ( e, settings, details ) {

 });
```

I even found this key **"drop"** in the **details** parameter, but it always had the value **false**.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a 'dragstop' event which would indicate end of dragging. If you couple that with a mouseup event you should have what you need.

Eg: on drag start you set a variable called isDragInProgress, which is checked on mouseup to decide if a drop is made. Reset it to false on completing the drop action if condition is true.

Comment: There is not such an event. The only event is to detect if there's a movement.

Comment: These are global event, not related to any plugin you are using, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drag

Comment: Please note that browser support for it is for IE10 and above only, if you are trying it in IE.